# How can I remove the try-catch block when I'm confident that an exception will never be thrown?

Tags: java, android

The try-catch block adds unnecessary lines to the code, making it appear cluttered. Since the value will always exist, it's unnecessary to include a try-catch block. What's the recommended way to use JsonObject without needing to handle exceptions using try-catch or throws after the method?

**Here is what I currently have:**

```
try {
    textViewOfcountryName.setText(new JSONObject("{\"EN\": \"Spain\", \"ES\": \"España\"}").getString(getString(R.string.iso_639)));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

**Here is what I'm looking for:**

```
textViewOfcountryName.setText(new JSONObject("{\"EN\": \"Spain\", \"ES\": \"España\"}").getString(getString(R.string.iso_639)));
```

Comment: `org.json.JSONException` extends `Exception`, so as a checked exception it must be handled.  Which means either catch it (as in your example), or update the method signature to throw the exception (icky).  From your example, that code snippet seems reasonable.  However, the code could be moved to a private method, which might make it feel less cluttered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really want to avoid the Try Catch, you can use the optString function from JSONObject.

getString throws an exception, so you either have to throw it yourself or put it inside a try catch

optString kinda do the same thing but can return a default String if no string is found, and doesn't throw an exception.

So you can effectively replace your code by

```
textViewOfcountryName.setText(new JSONObject(new HashMap<String, String>() {{ put("EN", "Spain"); put("ES", "España"); }}).optString(getString(R.string.iso_639)), "");
```

link to docs for optString: https://javadoc.io/static/org.json/json/20230227/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString-java.lang.String-

Comment: JSONObject's constructor throws JSONException, so your solution will not work.

Comment: https://javadoc.io/static/org.json/json/20230227/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject--

According to the documentation JSONObject constructor doesn't throw an exception if used with a map or no argument, therefore the code should be changed accordingly, but it quit defeats the purpose of a smaller code

Comment: In your solution you propose use constructor which consumes String... : new JSONObject("{\"EN\": \"Spain\", \"ES\": \"España\"}")

Answer (score 2):

If you are using lombok, you can annotate your method with @SneakyThrows:

```java
@SneakyThrows
void myMethod() {
    // ...
    textViewOfcountryName.setText(new JSONObject("{\"EN\": \"Spain\", \"ES\": \"España\"}").getString(getString(R.string.iso_639)));
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a utility function that takes a *Runnable* function that throws an Exception, executes it, and catches and rethrows the exceptions as *RuntimeExceptions*:

```java
public interface RunnableThrowingException<T extends Exception> {
    void run() throws T;
}

public static void sneaky(RunnableThrowingException<?> runnableThrowing) {
    try {
        runnableThrowing.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

You can re-use this everywhere you need it like this:

```
void myMethod() {
    // ...
    sneaky(() -> textViewOfcountryName.setText(new JSONObject("{\"EN\": \"Spain\", \"ES\": \"España\"}").getString(getString(R.string.iso_639))))
    // ...
}
```

If you don't want to define it yourself, you can always use a library like vavr or something similar for it: https://www.baeldung.com/exceptions-using-vavr

Answer (score 1):

In Java, if you are calling a method that throws a checked exception like `JSONException`, then you need to either handle the exception using a try-catch block or declare the exception to be thrown using the throws keyword.

So I think the only way to avoid try/catch block in this place is mark method as throwing `JSONException`.